# Android Get Text With Special Character From DB Using Json Into TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm using json to read long text from MySQL and set it on the TextView, it works without special characters but as soon as I have text like `"an apostrophe' like this one"` it returns null on textView. I tried using `Html.fromHtml` but it doesn't work. Any idea how I can use `setText(string_with_special_characters)`?

CODE:

```
public void accessWebService() {
         JsonRead task = new JsonRead();

      task.execute(new String[] { "http://mysite/myfile.php" });
     }

      try {
       JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
       JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("json_array");

       for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
        String chapter = jsonChildNode.optString("Column1");    

        TextView tvChapter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chapter);
        tvChapter.setText(Html.fromHtml(chapter));
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: @karimkhan posted code

Comment: post your json content

Comment: @njzk2 the json content (assuming you mean what is returned from the db by json) is a chapter from a book, it's very long, it's plain simple text with comas, question marks, apostrophes etc.. remove all those special characters and everything works however punctuation must not be ignored in my TextView and therefore require to have those special characters

Comment: you can parse json content and replace that special characters with others.

Comment: apostrophe is not a special character. It is in the ascii table, and therefore has the same value in most encodings (iso 8859, utf-8, cp 1252). Without more information on the content of the text, it is not possible to see what is wrong with it.

Comment: @njzk2 this works: "it is my birthday" AND THIS DOES NOT "it's my birthday"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question above, I have noticed the following strange behavior:

When I copy text (paragraph) from Microsoft Word and paste into MySQL column, TextView returns null, If I type out the entire paragraph within MySQL column TextView returns the paragraph string as expected. Copying text from Word to Scite or Notepad prior still doesn't work, typing the whole text out works. This is strange as you can't tell if text was copied and pasted or typed out in DB columns, looks exactly the same (including white space).

I can't retype everything... with the info given, please feel free to provide a solution otherwise I will be typing until next year

UPDATE

I have done further investigation:

Note the following apostrophe's

```
’  '
```

The one on the left is from text editors while the one on the right is from SQL.

SOLUTION:

```
UPDATE `mytable`SET `column` = replace(column, "’", "'");
```